# How to set a global font - SAPUI5

Tags: fonts, sapui5

I have check several ways to set a global SAPUI5 font but I am not able to do it. I have read different posts (not in Stakoverflow) but I did not find the correct solution, so I have decided to bring this question to our net.

How could I change globally the font in a SAPUI5 project? I think it is related to the used theme.

(Not sure if it's possible to change the default font-size, because i noticed that different SAPUI5 controls have different font-sizes defined in CSS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [SAP Theme Designer](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/a1/18094264684230bb6510045b5b5b7c/frameset.htm).

If you already have a new theme designed from it, to set it to Fiori application, you can do as mentioned [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/e9fc648661d84ed89360bbec3ae02611).

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    type="text/javascript"
    src="......../sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme-roots='{"my_theme" : "http://themes.org/ui5"}'>
</script>
```

Personal suggestion would be create a copy of existing theme and override whatever is necessary. Nice blog about it is [here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/09/19/create-and-apply-custom-theme-to-sapui5-application/)

If you are not interested in doing the above steps, you can just even load simple css file by overriding the classes
`sapThemeFontFamily`, `sapThemeFontSize` and load that css file by using `webapp/manifest.json`.

```
...
  "sap.ui5": {
    ... 
    "models": {
      ...
    },
    "resources": {
      "css": [
        {
          "uri": "css/style.css"
        }
      ]
    }

  }
```

[List of supported classes are here.](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/91a4946b0dcf4356aaaedc4e502864f4)

Answer (score 1):

SAP Theme Designer does not Support changing the font right now
(see the endless discussions on SCN ...)

We use the following workaround in our applications:

1. Make a custom CSS in your project folder, e.g. css\style.css
2. Include the CSS in your manifest.json

   ```
   "resources": {
       "css": [
           {
           uri": "css/style.css"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Set the following property, this excludes all SAP-Standard icons and their special fonts

   ```
    :not(.sapUiIcon) {
        font-family: Candara;
   }
   ```